# Openoffice Calc VLOOKUP with multiple sheets

Tags: vlookup, openoffice-calc

I am working with this data in Apache OpenOffice 4.1.2 with the goal of a vlookup that allows for cross sheet lookup of data in Sheet1 being added to Sheet2 base on the column pn. Here is the equation I have now but its not lining up right now. Any suggestions/corrections welcome.
In Sheet 2 using this.
`=VLOOKUP(A2; Sheet1.A2:Sheet1.C500; 2; 1)`
From What I understand Im expecting the code to return the information in the name column from Sheet1 based on the match of the pn column across all 500 rows.

```
Sheet1<br>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
|<th>code</th>|
|<th>name</th>|
|<th>pn</th>|
</tr>
</thead>
<br>
<tbody>
<tr>
|<td>111</td>|
|<td>one</td>|
|<td>101</td>|
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
|<td>112</td>|
|<td>two</td>|
|<td>102</td>|
</tr>
</table>
<br>
Sheet2<br>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
|<th>pn</th>|
|<th>qty</th>|
|<th>cur</th>|
</tr>
</thead>
<br>
<tbody>
<tr>
|<td>102</td>|
|<td>200</td>|
|<td>  $  </td>|
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
|<td>101</td>|
|<td>150</td>|
|<td>  $  </td>|
</tr>
</table>
```